# Can I use a nicer VSCode terminal window for Yocto devshell?

Tags: yocto, bitbake

In Yocto Dunfell, installed as described in [Yocto Project Quick Build](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/dunfell/brief-yoctoprojectqs/brief-yoctoprojectqs.html), `$ bitbake <recipe> -c devshell` opens xterm, which doesn't support copy-paste and other useful things.
Since I'm using VSCode, I would prefer integration with the VSCode Terminal window.

I tried replacing XTerm with TMux, but TMux keyboard shortcuts are terrible.
Is there a better way?